# how to retrieve multiple array json with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, elasticsearch, libraries

i know it sounds so easy. just use foreach looping or **json_decode**, and you can retrieve json data.

yeah it was, until i got multiple array json when trying retrieving data from elasticsearch.

im confused how to retrieve this :

```
{
  "took":3,
  "status": "taken",
  "_shards": {
               "total": 5,
               "successful": 5,
               "failed": 0
             },

  "hits": {
        "total":2,
        "msg":"ilusm",
        "hits":
                    [
                      {
                        //goes here
                        "id":1234
                      },

                      {
                        //goes here
                        "id":4321
                      }

                    ]

         },
  "date-created": "2016-06-06"
}
```

i use this to retrieve my first data :

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode($product),true);
echo "total took:";
echo $result['took'];   

echo "total shards:";
echo $result['_shards']['total'];
```

the problem is,i cant retrieve data inside hits. 
how can i retrieve hits id : 1234  ?

```
echo"view all total hits :";
echo $result['hits']['total'];
echo"view all total msg:";
echo $result['hits']['msg'];

echo"view hist data :";
echo json_decode(json_encode($result['hits']['hits']), true);
```

i got this **error** :

> Message: Array to string conversion

please help me to fix this out.
many thanks in advance.

Comment: print_r($result) and show your array.

Comment: `print_r($result);`show the output

Comment: $string = '{"took":3,"status": "taken","_shards": {"total": 5,"successful": 5,"failed": 0},"hits": {"total":2,"msg":"ilusm","hits":[{"id":1234},{"id":4321}]},"date-created": "2016-06-06"}';
$arr = json_decode($string, true);
var_dump($arr["hits"]["hits"][0]["id"]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it's work for me.

```
    $result= '{"took":3,"status": "taken","_shards": {"total": 5,"successful": 5,"failed": 0},"hits": {"total":2,"msg":"ilusm","hits":[{"id":1234},{"id":4321}]},"date-created": "2016-06-06"}';

    $array= json_decode($result, true);

    echo $array["hits"]["hits"][0]['id']; //output 1234
```

**output** **:** 1234

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '{"took":3,"status": "taken","_shards": {"total": 5,"successful": 5,"failed": 0},"hits": {"total":2,"msg":"ilusm","hits":[{"id":1234},{"id":4321}]},"date-created": "2016-06-06"}'; 

$hits= json_decode($string, true); 
$hits = $hits['hits']['hits'];
foreach($hits as $hitsIndex => $hitsValue){

 if($hitsValue["id"] == '1234'){
  var_dump($hitsValue["id"]);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused about json & php data management.

Should you tell us what $product variable is? (string,object/array).

Usually you get json data as string and parse it to php variables with json_decode.

Your Javascript-like object declaration of $product is useless.